# How to set value of struct indirectly in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, double-pointer

I would like to know, how to access first member of struct through pointer. I have tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo
{
    int a;
    char *str;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    int val = 10;
    *(int**)p = &val; //set the value of the first member of struct foo
    printf("%i\n",p->a);
}
```

but that print some garbage. How can I set it in similar manner?

Comment: I'm more curious about *why* you want to do something like this? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? If it's just plain curiosity that's okay, but please state so in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment should be:

```
*(int*)p = val;
```

You want to assign to an `int` member, so the pointer has to be a pointer to `int`, not pointer to pointer to `int`. And the value being assigned must be `int`; `&val` is a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Downvoting because the cast is unnecessary and should be avoided.

Comment: Why is the cast unnecessary? The type of `p` is `struct foo *`, you can't use that to assign to just the `int` member.

Comment: It's unnecessary because it can be trivially avoided. See my answer for how.

Comment: I took the definition of `p` as a given, and the question is about how to use that to assign to a member.

Comment: If you want to use p instead of an int*, you should just write `p->a = val`. The cast is just a bad idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no. cast to the initial member of struct, explicitly allowed.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt As I understand, the whole point of it is to do it without specifying the member by name.

Comment: There is no reason to do that.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Consider code that uses `offsetof()`. This is just a special case where the offset is `0`.

Comment: Sure, you can do it that way. In fact you can access all struct members using offsetof everywhere. But it's a bad idea to do it unless it is actually necessary, and hence shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing there is setting the value of `p->a` to the address of `val` (possibly truncated to 32 bits, depending on the implementation).

To access the field via a pointer, you have to take the field's address and then assign to the dereferenced pointer.

```c
int *pa = &p->a;
*pa = val;
```

Of course you can also just write `p->a = val`. Note that `p->a` is just an abbreviation for `(*p).a`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `*(int**)p` effectively treats `a` as an `int*` instead of an `int`, so it was doubly wrong in that way too.

Comment: Right, I completely missed that!